# gradle error : failed linked references can’t fix

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I had a backgroundCustom.png file in drawables. I have no idea how I got it there and didn't notice the capital letter. A month later I wanted to launch the project, but it failed bc of the register, of course, when I change the register or delete a file, it writes an error that I can’t fix. I cleared the cache, the project, and rebuilt the project. It's all to no avail. And a stalemate results: if there is a file, it complains about the register, if not, the error is below. The file itself is not used anywhere in the project.

Error:

Android resource linking failed com.project.tori.app-mergeDebugResources-43:/values/values.xml:2227: error: resource drawable/backgroundCustom (aka com.project.tori:drawable/backgroundCustom) not found. com.project.tori.app-mergeDebugResources-43:/values/values.xml:2227: error: resource drawable/backgroundCustom (aka com.project.tori:drawable/backgroundCustom) not found. error: failed linking references.

I cleared the cache, the project, and rebuilt the project. Tried to update AndroidStudio version,sdk
tried to downgrade appcompat